# AppFabric: DataCache.Remove always fails

Tags: appfabric, appfabric-cache

I'm writing code to remove a cache entry from non-Azure AppFabric (v1.1).  In the code snippet below, DataCache.Remove is always returning false...

```
object bogusData = new object();

_cache.Put(account, bogusData, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.0));
Sleep(1000); // for testing purposes

// we don't need the contents of the cache entry, we just want to know
// if the account is in the cache or not...
object cachedData = _cache.Get(account);

// if we don't find it in the cache, it is already been removed (or expired), so return true.
if (cachedData == null)
    return true;

Sleep(1000); // for testing purposes

// this always returns false
bool status = _cache.Remove(account);
```

By design, in the above code snippet, cachedData is always != null.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woot!

I figured it out, calling DataCache.Remove(key) will attempt to remove the item from the default region.  While, not clearly shown above (_cache is a thin wrapper around DataCache), our Put/Get calls include a region name, but our Remove did not.  I added the Region and the Remove worked properly.